# Aligning text in Card, reactrap

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

So I want to align the text next to the image, but here is what I get

[image: history]

Here is my code

```
<Card>
        <div class='container'>
          <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-12 col-md-5 mt-3'>
              <CardImg src={history.image} alt={history.name} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='row'>
            <div className='col-12 col-md-5 mt-3'>
              <CardBody>
                <CardText>{history.description}</CardText>
              </CardBody>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</Card>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Theo.

Answer (score 1):

Try using flex property to container!

Using CSS:

```
.container {
   display: flex;
}
```

I think you are using Bootstrap, this might be helpful to you!

[Flex Property Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/)